# Nginx rewrite & return - why is this working?

Tags: nginx

I'm writing an application to provide read-only access to a number of legacy applications. I want to use Nginx to redirect from the old URLs to a single new URL like this:

Old URL: `http://oldsite.com/?value=something`

New URL: `http://newsite.com/?value=something&source=oldsite`

Here's my Nginx server block for `oldsite.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name oldsite;
    return 301 $scheme://newsite.com$request_uri&source=oldsite;
}
```

This works perfectly - put in the `oldsite.com` URL and you're redirected to the correct `newsite.com` URL.

But I'm confused by the following behaviour:

Enter `http://oldsite.com` in the browser

I expect to be redirected to `http://newsite.com&source=oldsite`.

Instead, I'm redirected to `http://newsite.com`.

I think what might be happening is this: when the `$request_uri` is empty or null, Nginx stops processing the string and returns whatever it has.

While this *is* what I want, it is not what I expected. I have not been able to find any mention of this in the Nginx documentation and I don't want to rely on an undocumented "feature".

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Try running the request with wget to see the actual redirect. The URL you are returning is invalid if the request doesn't contain any parameters (parameters are separated by the path with a ?). I could imagine that the client drops everything from the first unexpected character (&)

Comment: Great suggestion! Interestingly, I get a 500 error when I do that because it's redirecting to `http://newsite.com/&source=oldsite`. Copying this URL to the browser (chrome) also results in the 500 error. But when the browser gets the 301 response directly, it appears to do what you suggest, removing everything from the & symbol on.

Comment: You should consider using `rewrite` instead of `return` as it handles optional parameters correctly. E.g. `rewrite ^ $scheme://newsite.com$uri?source=oldsite permanent;`